# Every subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, has a subset of the Borel sigma-algebra containing it that has the same measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to find a proof for this: for all $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, there is a subset (correction: element) $B$ of the Borel sigma-algebra, such that $A \subseteq B$ and $m^*_n(A) = m_n(B)$, where $m_n$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $m^*_n$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.

I am using [Folland](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160) and it doesn't seem to have this theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Using the definition of Lebesgue outer measure, it is easy to show there exists a sequence $(B_i)_{i \geq 1}$ of open sets with $A \subset B_i$ for all $i$, and $m(B_i) \to m^*(A)$ as $i \to \infty$.  Define $B= \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty B_i$. $B$ is a Borel set with $A \subset B$ and $m^*(A)=m(B)$.

I left a couple of small holes for you to fill in, to justify some of the statements above.

Comment: Was stuck because it didn't occur to me to construct $B$ from the definition of the outer measure. Thanks!

Comment: Cause I'm such a good student :) ... 1) outer measure defn says $m^*(A) =$ inf of "volume" of all possible cover of $A$ by "open n-dim rectangles". 2) if set of all coverings is infinite, keep picking an open cover $B_i$ with lower inf, if finite, repeat the cover with least "volume" infinitely. 3) open sets generates Borel sigma-algebra, close under countable intersection, so $B$ is Borel set. 4) Finally Borel sets are Lebesgue measurable so $m^(B) = m^*(B) = m^*(B \cap A) + m^*(B \cap A^c) = m^*(B \cap A) = m^*(A)$.

Comment: @JeanValjean : by the way, you can use closed instead of open rectangles and it leads to the same $m^*(A)$.  This is occasionally useful.  Regarding 2), I cannot imagine how the set of all coverings could be finite.  I just picked $B_i$ open with $A \subset B_i$ and $m(B_i) < m^*(A) + 1/i$.  I proved 4) using more basic facts, without using the fact that Borel sets are Lebesgue measurable, but your proof is slicker.

Comment: Thanks for the additional input! 1) Oh, so for any $1/i$ there must be a cover $B_i$ such that $m(B_i) < m^*(A) + 1/i$, if not $m^*(A) + 1/i$ would be the inf instead? Also, we are assuming $A$ has finite outer measure, if not just let $B$ be the whole space right?

Comment: @JeanValjean : by definition of Lebesgue outer measure, for any $i \in \mathbb{N}^+$ there _must_ exist an open set $B_i$ where $B_i$ is a union of open intervals with total length $< m^*(A) + 1/i$, and by definition of Lebesgue outer measure again, $m(B_i)=m^*(B_i) < m^*(A)+1/i$.  There is no "if not" case, so I'm not sure what you mean.  And yes, if $m^*(A)=\infty$, you can just tak4 $B=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I mean "if not, it would be a contradiction". $B_i$ must exists because $m*(A)$ is defined to be the infimum of all such covers. Thanks for the help!